# Query to get all drivers making less than a set amount and nearest city

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a SQL query that will give me a list of van drivers who have earned less than a certain dollar amount along with the nearest city to their current location. I ~think~ what I've written will work but I killed it after 20 minutes of running.

3 tables: Pay - key is driver_id and I have to retrieve driver_id and total_pay where pay is 'Y'
trip - key is id and I have to retrieve the trip id for trips with a status of 'P'
trip_position - key is a different id and I have to retrieve the nearest location.
there are a ton of locations so I have to sort it by the trip_date desc to
get the current one.

my query:

```
select pay.driver_id, sum(pay.total_pay), trip.id, trip.location, trip_date
from pay 
join trip on trip.driver=pay.driver_id and trip.status='P'
join trip_position on trip.id=trip_position.trip_id 
     and trip_position.trip_date=( 
         select top 1 trip_date 
         from trip_position 
         where trip.id=trip_position.trip_id 
         order by trip_date desc
     )
where pay.pay_status='Y' 
group by driver_id, trip.id, trip.location, trip.date 
having sum(pay.total_pay) < 1000.00 
order by driver_id
```

my original query was this:

```
select pay.driver_id, sum(pay.total_pay), trip.id, trip.location, trip_date
from pay 
join trip on trip.driver=pay.driver_id and trip.status='P'
join trip_position on trip.id=trip_position.trip_id 
where pay.pay_status='Y' 
group by driver_id, trip.id, trip.location, trip.date 
having sum(pay.total_pay) < 1000.00 
order by driver_id
```

the problem is it gave me all the positions for that particular driver, not just the most current one:

```
driver_id  total_pay  trip_id   trip.location   trip_date
bob        976        1234567   1st street      2023-04-11
bob        976        1234567   2nd street      2023-04-10
bob        976        1234567   3rd street      2023-04-09
fred       300        3344556   4th street      2023-04-11
fred       300        3344556   5th street      2023-04-10
```

I need to show each driver, their total pay, the current trip_id and their current location.  The problem is there's nothing that says "this is the current location", it's strictly based on date.

ideally, it would look like this:

```
bob        976         1234567  1st street      2023-04-11
fred       300         3344556  4th street      2023-04-11
```

Comment: Please ensure you provide both sample data and desired results to illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are there are two things you need.

1. find the total pay for the drivers who have completed legit trips and has their pay below a certain number.
2. From 1, get the get their latest trip data along with other columns.

Here we can make use of cte to get the results.

```
with original_query
  as (select pay.driver_id
            , sum(pay.total_pay) as total_pay
            , trip.id
            , trip.location as trip_location
            , trip_date
        from pay 
        join trip 
          on trip.driver=pay.driver_id 
         and trip.status='P'
        join trip_position 
          on trip.id=trip_position.trip_id 
       where pay.pay_status='Y' 
       group by driver_id
                , trip.id
                , trip.location
                , trip.date 
        having sum(pay.total_pay) < 1000.00          
        )
    ,latest_position
     as (select row_number() over(partition by driver_id,total_pay,trip_id order by trip_date desc) as rnk
                ,driver_id
                ,total_pay
                ,trip_id
                ,trip_location
                ,trip_date
           from original_query
          )
    select *
      from latest_position
     where rnk=1
```